# Como fazer uma consulta JPA com mapeamentos @ManyToMany

Tags: java, select, jpa

Bom dia.

Estou com dificuldades em realizar uma consulta na base de dados onde minha entidade Employee tem 2 mapeamentos @ManyToMany e 1 mapeamento @ManyToOne.
Ao realizar uma consulta os dados de Employee e Projects são retornados sem maiores problemas.
Os atributos relacionais do ManyToMany que está sendo um problema.
Para fazer a inserção está ocorrendo ok.
Para buscar na base um problema.
Alguém pode ajudar por gentileza?
Obrigado

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@JsonView
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_employee;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", length = 120)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role", length = 100)
    private String role;

    @NotNull
    private Double salary;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "manager", length = 120)
    private String manager;

    private int gcm;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Projects project;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_skill",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_employee"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_skill")
    )

    private List<Skill> skill;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_certification",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_employee"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_certification")
    )

    private List<Certification> certification;
}
```

Classe skill

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
@JsonView
public class Skill implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_skill;

    @NotNull
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skill", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> employee;

    public Skill(){}
}
```

Classe certification

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "certification")
@JsonView
public class Certification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_certification;

    @NotNull
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "certification", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employee;

    public Certification(){}

    public Certification(String descricao){
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
}
```

Classe projects

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@JsonView
public class Projects implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_project;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 150)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "customer", length = 100)
    private String customer;

    private Double valueOfProject;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_Begin")
    private Calendar dtBegin;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_End")
    private Calendar dtEnd;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<Employee> employee;

    public Projects(){}

}
```

Comment: Poderia postar na resposta, onde vc faz a chama da Employe e qual seria os erros ocorrido

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo um exemplo das classes Certification e Employee, acredito que isso possa ajudar:

```
List<Certification> findByEmployee_Name(String name);
```

Outro exemplo passando uma lista de nomes:

```
 List<Certification> findByEmployee_NameIn(List<String> name);
```

Comment: O que eu desejo Kaique é que quando eu busque todos os Employee cadastrados, que retorne junto as skill dele e as certificações que ele possui

Comment: Ao fazer um debug deu o seguinte erro:

Comment: 2018-12-22 11:51:32.069  WARN 6064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Comment: você consegue executar List<Employee> findAll()? Da interface CrudRepository

Comment: Consigo sim, porém ocorre o erro acima.

Comment: Os dados de Employee e Project retornam normal. O que não está vindo são os dados de Skill e Certification

Comment: Tente trocar isso  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_skill") por  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id_skill")  e também joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id_employee"),

Comment: Não adiantou também Kaique

Comment: Tente fazer configurando a relação manytomany nos métodos get and set como no exemplo a seguir: [link](https://hellokoding.com/restful-api-example-with-spring-boot-spring-data-rest-spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-relationship-and-mysql/) Caso ainda não dê certo acho que vai ser o jeito criar uma coluna smente para relacionar as duas.